# Grouping JSON output by an attribute

Tags: java, arrays, handler

I have a source JSON string I would like to convert into local-attributed JSON. I'm trying to achieve:

```
    {
      "dep": 1552928400000,
      "des": "USA",
      "listWagonDetail": [
          {
              "listSeatDetail": [
                  {
                      "seatColumn": "A",
                      "seatRow": "1",
                      "seatStatus": "1",
                      "subclass": "C"
                  },
                  {
                      "seatColumn": "A",
                      "seatRow": "2",
                      "seatStatus": "0",
                      "subclass": "C"
                  },
                  {
                      "seatColumn": "A",
                      "seatRow": "3",
                      "seatStatus": "1",
                      "subclass": "C"
                  }
              ],
              "numSeat": 0,
              "wagonCode": "PRE",
              "wagonNo": "1"
          },
          {
              "listSeatDetail": [
                  {
                      "seatColumn": "A",
                      "seatRow": "1",
                      "seatStatus": "0",
                      "subclass": "C"
                  },
                  {
                      "seatColumn": "A",
                      "seatRow": "2",
                      "seatStatus": "0",
                      "subclass": "C"
                  },
                  {
                      "seatColumn": "A",
                      "seatRow": "3",
                      "seatStatus": "1",
                      "subclass": "C"
                  }
              ],
              "numSeat": 0,
              "wagonCode": "PRE",
              "wagonNo": "2"
          }
     ],
      "numWagon": 0,
      "org": "AU",
      "subClass": null,
      "trainNo": "77"
  }
```

Which is to group each listSeatDetail by WagonNo. But instead I got this on my work where "numSeat", "wagonCode" and "WagonNo" is looped every listSeatDetail and only the last data of each array are shown:

```
{
    "dep": 1552928400000,
    "des": "USA",
    "listWagonDetail": [
        {
            "listSeatDetail": [
                {
                    "seatColumn": "A",
                    "seatRow": "3",
                    "seatStatus": "1",
                    "subclass": "C"
                }
            ],
            "numSeat": 0,
            "wagonCode": "PRE",
            "wagonNo": "2"
        },
        {
            "listSeatDetail": [
                {
                    "seatColumn": "A",
                    "seatRow": "3",
                    "seatStatus": "1",
                    "subclass": "C"
                }
            ],
            "numSeat": 0,
            "wagonCode": "PRE",
            "wagonNo": "2"
        },
        {
            "listSeatDetail": [
                {
                    "seatColumn": "A",
                    "seatRow": "3",
                    "seatStatus": "1",
                    "subclass": "C"
                }
            ],
            "numSeat": 0,
            "wagonCode": "PRE",
            "wagonNo": "2"
        },
```

How can I achieve the first JSON? Here is part of my code:

```
private void generateSeat(GetSeatRequest request, GetSeatMapResponse seatMapResponse,
        SeatMapResponsePojo seatmapResponsePojo) {

    seatMapResponse.setDepDate(request.getDepDate());
    seatMapResponse.setDes(request.getDes());
    seatMapResponse.setOrg(request.getOrg());
    seatMapResponse.setTrainNo(request.getTrainNo());
    seatMapResponse.setNumWagon(0);
    seatMapResponse.setSubClass(request.getSubClass());

    List<WagonDetail> listWagonDetail = new ArrayList<>();
    for (SeatMapPojo seatmap : seatmapResponsePojo.getPayload()) {

        WagonDetail wagon = new WagonDetail();
        String wagonNoString = seatmap.getStamformdetcode();
        String[] wagonNo = wagonNoString.split("-");            

        for (WagonDetail wagondetail : listWagonDetail) {

            wagondetail.setNumSeat(0);
            wagondetail.setWagonCode(wagonNo[0]);
            wagondetail.setWagonNo(wagonNo[1]);

            List<SeatDetail> listSeatDetail = new ArrayList<>();
            SeatDetail seatDetail = new SeatDetail();

            seatDetail.setSeatColumn(seatmap.getWagondetcol());
            seatDetail.setSeatRow(seatmap.getWagondetrow());
            seatDetail.setSeatStatus(seatmap.isIsavilable() ? "0" : "1");
            seatDetail.setSubclass(seatmap.getSubclass());
            listSeatDetail.add(seatDetail);

            wagondetail.setListSeatDetail(listSeatDetail);
        }


        listWagonDetail.add(wagon);
    }

    seatMapResponse.setListWagonDetail(listWagonDetail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use [google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), which is the best serialize/deserialize Library of JSON so far we found.

which you could define the desired class like this:

```
class Output{
    private int depDate;
    private String des;
    ...
    private List<WagonDetail> listWagonDetail;

    //... getter()/setter()

}
```

then you could define `WagonDetail`:

```
class WagonDetail{

     private List<SeatDetail> listSeatDetail;
     private int numSeat;
     ....
}
```

then class `SeatDetail` so on

And you could use gson to serialize that class Output pretty easily:

```
Output output = new Output();
//set according attributes using setter/getter
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsStr = gson.toJson(output);
```

Deserialize the JSON string to an object is easily too:

```
String jsStr = "..."
Gson gson = new Gson();
Output output = gson.fromJson(jsStr, Output.class);
```

Comment: I'm using flexjson at the moment, and the problem was the attribute response from server and the attribute of local API is different, so I had to convert every data from the response JSON into local-friendly JSON. So I was trying to achieve the first JSON on the questions above but instead gotten the undesired result. It must be a mistake on my looping, but I'm not sure on which part..

Comment: to my practice, if the structures are the same but only with different attribute names, there is annotation to do that, if structures are different, clearest way to do that is first mapping the response JSON to a response object then map that response object to the object with structure that is desired, it will be horrible try to build that JSON struct with bare hands. always let the mapper logical of the JSON serialize/deserialize library to do that for you. You just have to define the right structure of the class.